# Datepart not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The main problem I seem to be having with the code below is with the datepart formulas. I am trying to pull back monthly recurring revenue as of the end of the prior month (for any given month end) for all months going back in time, and only revenue changes made in that calendar month going back in time. However, what's odd is I can change the "-1" in the datepart formula to absolutely anything and it brings back the same values. What's happening no matter what I change it to, for, say, 2/28/2017 is that it brings back March changes only.

```
  Select P.End_Date as "Period",
  (Select sum(RMR_Amount) FROM ABC_Final.dbo.AR_RMR_Tracking as Tracking
  inner join ABC_Final.dbo.AR_Customer_Site as Site on Site.Customer_Site_Id 
  = Tracking.Site_Id 

  where Tracking.Effective_Date <=eomonth(dateadd(m,-1,P.End_Date),0) 
  and Tracking.Effective_Date <= '3/31/2017' and 
  datepart(m,dateadd(m,-1,Tracking.Effective_Date)) = 
  datepart(m,dateadd(m,-1,P.End_Date)) 
  and Site.Business_name not like 
  '%Dog%') as "Beginning Monthly RMR" 
  FROM ABC_FINAL.DBO.so_ACCOUNTING_PERIOD as P 
  WHERE End_Date <= '3/31/2017'
```

Comment: too many conditions... i reckon these stopped what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: comment out your conditions one by one and work out which one is causing the issue. SQL just does what you tell it. It might even be that business names not like dog don't have any other transactions. No one can solve this because it's related to your data. You need to undertake some basic troubleshooting,

Comment: this line where Tracking.Effective_Date <=eomonth(dateadd(m,-1,P.End_Date),0) 
  and Tracking.Effective_Date <= '3/31/2017' and 
  datepart(m,dateadd(m,-1,Tracking.Effective_Date)) = 
  datepart(m,dateadd(m,-1,P.End_Date))  --- does not make sense

Comment: I have done troubleshooting and narrowed it down I think to the datepart formula since I can change that -1 to any number and still get the same results. I will continue to troubleshoot. Thanks.

Comment: I figured it out by changing 
  datepart(m,dateadd(m,-1,Tracking.Effective_Date)) = 
  datepart(m,dateadd(m,-1,P.End_Date)) to datepart(m,dateadd(m,-0,Tracking.Effective_Date)) = 
  datepart(m,dateadd(m,-1,P.End_Date))